# Why does toc_depth doesn't work with rmarkdown theme?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to create a Rmarkdown html report with the `downcute` (chaos) theme from the package `rmdformats`. Now everything works except for the `toc_depth` argument in my `yaml` header. The table of contents will only show `h1` and `h2`'s.

```
install.packages("rmdformats")
```

```
---
title: "Title"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output:
  rmdformats::downcute:
    code_folding: hide
    toc_depth: 5
    self_contained: true
    thumbnails: false
    lightbox: true
    downcute_theme: "chaos"
pkgdown:
  as_is: true
---

# h1

## h2

### h3

#### h4

##### h5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `rmdformats::downcute()` only works with `toc_depth` 2 or less out of the box. There are plenty of issues on rmdformats [GitHub page](https://github.com/juba/rmdformats/issues?q=is%3Aissue+toc_depth) where this is discussed for different themes.

However, based on one answer for [this issue](https://github.com/juba/rmdformats/issues/81), you can get `toc_depth: 5` by pasting this into the start of your R Markdown file:

```
<style>
#toc ul.nav li ul li {
    display: none;
    max-height: none;
}

#toc ul.nav li.active ul li  {
    display: block;
    max-height: none;
}

#toc ul.nav li ul li ul li {
    max-height: none;
    display: none !important;
}

#toc ul.nav li ul li.active ul li {
    max-height: none;
    display: block !important;
}
</style>
```

Note that this will ruin the smooth animation of the toc.